# как можно исправить эту ошибку? C++

Tags: c++

Debug Assertion Failed!
Line:52
Expression:_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)

```
#pragma once

#ifndef _WARGAME_H
#define _WARGAME_H
#include "warplayer.h"
#include "deck.h"
#include <iostream>


const int NUMPLAYERS = 2;     //number of players in the game

class WarGame {


private:

    WarPlayer* arrPlayer[NUMPLAYERS];              //the array of players
    Deck *decks = new Deck();   

public:

    WarGame(WarPlayer *name1, WarPlayer *name2);
    void printStatus();        
    WarGame(const WarGame& other);             
    ~WarGame();                                    
    WarPlayer* startGame(int rounds);  
    WarPlayer* tie(Card* c1, Card* c2); 

};
#endif //  !_WARGAME__H 



WarGame::~WarGame() {

    arrPlayer[0]->~WarPlayer();    cout<< "\n" << endl;
    arrPlayer[1]->~WarPlayer();    cout<< "\n" << endl;

    delete[] arrPlayer[0];     //delete first player
    delete[] arrPlayer[1];     //delete second player
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Ну что же вы делаете!

1. Дважды вызываете деструктор `WarPlayer`! при удалении деструктор вызывается автоматически!
2. И непонятно что - применяя delete[] к отдельному элементу - или у вас `arrPlayer` указывает на динамически выделенный массив? Тут у вас вообще какая-то жуткая нестыковка - вы бы показали, что такое `WarPlayer` и как инициализируется массив `arrPlayer` - без этого трудно советовать, **как надо** поступить.

Вот и получаете, скорее всего, при повторном освобождении памяти поврежденную внутреннюю структуру...